# Read custom action from msi using VB script

Tags: vbscript, windows-installer

I want to read particular custom action from MSI using VBScript. 
    like, i wanted to display particular string from custom action using VBScript.
    As I'am not so good in scripting, so i dont have any code with me. Please help.
    Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Basically a dumb vbscript to display something from a script custom action can be msgbox "hello". However I don't understand what you mean exactly. You can display a string from within a custom action only if you have already written the custom action and it's vbscript. For example, if there's a C++ custom action that runs during the install, you can't use vbscript to display anything from it. You can't "read particular custom action from MSI" because a custom action is a piece of code that runs during an install operation, so how can you read it? If you are examining the MSI file and you want to know what's in it, including any vbscripts, you can use Orca to find them. 
So I think you may need to better explain exactly what you're trying to do.